# Assign InPlaceEdit dynamically to TextFields created by RowRepeater

Tags: sapui5

How would you assign a [InPlaceEdit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/InPlaceEdit.html) control to TextFields which ware created dynamically via databinding with a RowRepeater?

Basically I have something like this:

```
someRowRepeater.bindRows("/path/to/an/array", new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{value}"});
```

The array looks like this:

```
[{text: "some first value"}, {text: "some second value"}, ... ]
```

I already tried to add an *id* to each TextField, so I could add the *InPlaceEdits* using `.byID()` in the *onAfterRendering* method, by modifying the array to `[{text: "some first value", id: 0}, ...]` and the constructor of the TextField to `...TextField({text: "{value}", id: "{value}" + "{id}"});` but then I'm getting the error message that `"{value}{id}" is not a valid ID.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.ux3,sap.ui.table,sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
        </script>

        <script>
            var data = {rows: [{text: "some first value"}, {text: "some second value"}]};
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);

            var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
                title: "Table column and data binding",
                showNoData : true,  
                columnHeaderHeight : 10,
            });
            oTable.setModel(oModel);

            oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: "My Column",
                template: new sap.ui.commons.InPlaceEdit("IPE1",{
                    content: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{text}"})
                }),
            }));

            oTable.bindRows("/rows");

            oTable.placeAt("content");
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.